# How to use ant call

Tags: ant

When i try to run the following from windows command prompt, it is working fine.

```
ant Reports -f C:/EAR_XMLS/InfraCopy.xml "-Dsource=C:\Console" "-Ddestination=C:/INFRA" "-DAPP_NAME=TEST_FCJ"
```

How to run the same in build.xml (ANT)? I dont prefer EXEC option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ant antfile="C:/EAR_XMLS/InfraCopy.xml" target="Reports">
  <property name="source" value="C:\Console"/>
  <property name="destination" value="C:/INFRA"/>
  <property name="APP_NAME" value="TEST_FCJ"/>
</ant>
```

See docs [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) for more details.